# pdf of combined models

Tags: probability, distributions

In a question, I have 5 systems. At a given time x, the probability that they're working is based on an exponential distribution. The combination of all systems will work if any single system is working

- Systems fail independently

How can I determine the pdf of the system reliability? (ie. the lifetime of the system)

---

My current process

The exponential function: $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$
Therefore, the probability of a system failing is $1-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$
Therefore, the probability of all systems failing at time x is $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{5}(1-\lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i x})$
So all systems working would be $p = 1- \prod\limits_{i=1}^{5}(1-\lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i x})$

Very unclear to me

Comment: $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ is pdf, which is not probability. You need cdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $T_i$ as the lifetime of system $i$; then, your total system lifetime, $T=\max(T_1..T_5)$. You'll first write $F_T(t)=P(T\leq t)=\prod_{i=1}^5 P(T_i\leq t)$, and differentiate wrt $t$.

Your *probability of system failing* expression is wrong. You seem to confuse probability with density. P(A system fails before time $t$) = $P(T_i \leq t)=\int_0^{t}{\lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i x}dx}=1-e^{-\lambda_i t}$.

Comment: So the pdf of all systems working would be $pdf = \frac{d}{dx} [1 - \prod \limits _{i=1}^5 (1 - e^{-\lambda_i x})]$? I think I'm still a little bit confused aboud pdf vs cdf. It seems to me that pdf is the probability at one point, where cdf is the sum of all previous probabilities

Comment: Yes, pdf of total system's lifetime. You're right about CDF, but PDF is not probability. Think of uniform RV in [0,1/2] range. PDF value is 2, is it a probability?